# Consecutive vowels counting ending up in an infinite loop

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program that will read in a file, and find the word in the file that has the greatest number of consecutive vowels. I am doing this by getting each new word from the file, turning it into a charArray, and then evaluating the characters in the array to see if they are a vowel. A counter is kept for the number of consecutive vowels, and then if the counter for the current word is greater than the greatest previous counter value, the variable maxVowelString is set to the value of the current counter.

I have already resolved a number of errors with how I was handling the charArray, but when I run this in terminal, it does nothing, just ends up in an infinite loop. I can't figure out what's causing it. Does anyone have any ideas? (I am a bit new at coding, so there may be a logic error or something I don't understand).

**Update:** I made several of the suggested changes, and went through and debugged it. The program is getting stuck in this specific loop, but I can't figure out why.

```
    while ((i + n) < lowercase.length())    
                {
                    System.out.println("i + n " + (i + n));
                    if ((charsList.get(i+n) == 'a') || (charsList.get(i+n) == 'e') || (charsList.get(i+n) == 'i') || (charsList.get(i+n) == 'o') || (charsList.get(i+n) == 'u'))
                    {
                        isVowel = true;
                        counter++;
                        System.out.println("counter " + counter);
                        i++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        isVowel = false;
                    } 
                }
```

Comment: `while (isVowel = true)` will always be true as you are assigning the value true to isVowel. If you want comparison need `==`, but then it's pretty much going to be an infinite loop as you never set it to false.

Comment: I just realized both of those, and fixed them (just updated it), but it still isn't working.

Comment: refine logic , just check the char if it's a vowel continue,  else go out of the loop, at the end compare the current count with max count if  greater then change max else go on, next word

Answer (score 0):

You have flaw at second while loop, where you are iterating over the word. Setting n=1 and counter=0 is causing the infinite loop when it finds the next letter as vowel. It iterates infinitely on same letter. Below is the updated code snippet (only logic updated) :

```
while (fileIn.hasNext())
{
    word = fileIn.next();
    String lowercase = word.toLowerCase();
        char[] wordChar = word.toCharArray();
        int i = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        while (i < lowercase.length()) {
            if ((wordChar[i] == 'a') || (wordChar[i] == 'e') || (wordChar[i] == 'i') || (wordChar[i] == 'o')
                    || (wordChar[i] == 'u')) {
                counter++;
            } else {
                i++;
                continue;
            }
            i++;

        }
        if (counter > maxVowelString) {
            maxVowelString = counter;
            maxVowelWord = lowercase;
        }
}
    System.out.println("The word in this file with the most consecutive vowels is " + maxVowelWord + ".");
    System.out.println("It has " + maxVowelString + "vowels.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,the line if(fileIn.hasNext()) is wrong.Replace it with while(fileIn.hasNext())..This is because as you are reading from a file you dont know when it ends so this while loop will check whether your file has a next word..Note - When you call hasNext() read from the file, otherwise you will always have an infinite loop(This is only a general information as you are reading(word = fileIn.next()) from the file there is no issue ).

Secondly,look this while loop-

`while (isVowel == true)
            {
                counter = 0;
                int n = 1;
                if ((wordChar[i+n] == 'a') || (wordChar[i+n] == 'e') ||  wordChar[i+n] == 'i') || (wordChar[i+n] == 'o') || (wordChar[i+n] == 'u'))
                {
                    isVowel = true;
                    counter++;
                }
                else
                    isVowel = false;
                n++;
            }`

Now suppose a word "Queueing" -the first if condition is true when n=1;and then counter++;loop again runs and now n=2 if condition satisfied and so on till the last vowel that is 'i' is encountered..Now,accordingly what is the value of i (just see it)....So,to make it correct this must be the below loop..

```
`while (isVowel == true)
        {
            counter = 0;
            int n = 1;
            if ((wordChar[i+n] == 'a') || (wordChar[i+n] == 'e') ||  wordChar[i+n] == 'i') || (wordChar[i+n] == 'o') || (wordChar[i+n] == 'u'))
            {
                isVowel = true;
                counter++;i++;
            }
            else{
                isVowel = false;
                i++;continue;
            }
            n++;
        }`
```

As you want to start from the position upto where you have checked..

Hope this might help you.